# Unexpected token 'where' when querying

Tags: apex

I have a search query against some records but when I am trying to search i am receiving the error in the title, could someone take a quick look at this and let me know where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

```
public static String doSearchCompletedApp(String columnName, String sortTyp, String searchVal){
    String valSearch = '%' + searchVal + '%';
    String query = 'Select Name, Source_Code__c, Sent_to_GNA__c, PTI__c, First_Name__c, Family_Name__c, Card_Status__c, ' + 
                                'Card_Status_Date__c, Card_Delivery__c, Campaign__c, Application__r.Name, Application__c ' + 
                            ' FROM Card_Application__c ' + 
                            ' Where Send_to_AMEX__c = \'YES\' ' + 
                                ' AND Hours_Since_Sent_For_Processing__c <= 1560 ' +
                                ' AND (Card_Status__c = \'Approved\' OR Card_Status__c = \'Declined\') ' + 
                                ' Where ' + columnName + ' like: valSearch ' + //error appears to be due to this
                            ' Order by ' + columnName + ' ' + sortTyp +    
                            ' LIMIT 10';
    //Error unexpected token 'where'
    //Error unexpected token 'null'             
    return JSON.serialize(Database.query(query));
```

Comment: why 2 times Where  condition. second time it should be AND....... `' Where ' + columnName + ' like: valSearch ' +` this line

Answer (score 2):

You should replace **WHERE** with **AND**.

```
public static String doSearchCompletedApp(String columnName, String sortTyp,     String searchVal){
    String valSearch = '%' + searchVal + '%';
    String query = 'Select Name, Source_Code__c, Sent_to_GNA__c, PTI__c, First_Name__c, Family_Name__c, Card_Status__c, ' + 
                            'Card_Status_Date__c, Card_Delivery__c, Campaign__c, Application__r.Name, Application__c ' + 
                        ' FROM Card_Application__c ' + 
                        ' Where Send_to_AMEX__c = \'YES\' ' + 
                            ' AND Hours_Since_Sent_For_Processing__c <= 1560 ' +
                            ' AND (Card_Status__c = \'Approved\' OR Card_Status__c = \'Declined\') ' + 
                            ' AND' + columnName + ' like: valSearch ' + //replace WHERE with AND. You already have a WHERE above
                        ' Order by ' + columnName + ' ' + sortTyp +    
                        ' LIMIT 10';            
return JSON.serialize(Database.query(query));
```

Comment: Trying now think you might be right.